# Which model should I select for a Multivariate Time Series interpolation where I have covariates and missing dates?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series

I have data with the sales of stores across a two year timespan. Sample data:

| Date | Target Store Sales | Target Store Promotion | Sales_Store1 | Promotion_Store1 | Sales_Store2 | Promotion_Store1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-27 | 30.0 | No | 29.0 | Yes | 34.0 | Yes |
| 2022-06-28 | 42.0 | No | Null | No | 39.0 | No |
| 2022-06-29 | 37.0 | No | 26.0 | Yes | 37.0 | Yes |
| 2022-07-02 | 45.0 | No | 44.0 | No | Null | No |
| 2022-07-03 | 29.0 | No | Null | Yes | 24.0 | Yes |
| 2022-07-05 | 34.0 | No | 40.0 | No | 42.0 | No |

To expand on my (hopefully correct) question title, what I wish to do is use the table above as my training set to predict the **baseline** for the sales of my Target store, hoping to find the uplift of a specific promotion. The table has been filtered on the Target Store Promotion column so that it only contains the days where there was no Promotion. Promotions run on a daily basis. Sales_Store1 and Promotion_Store1 contain the sales and Promotion status of similar stores. I am fairly confident in their selection.

The remainder of the example table is below:

| Date | Target Store Sales | Target Store Promotion | Sales_Store1 | Promotion_Store1 | Sales_Store2 | Promotion_Store1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-30 | 55.0 | Yes | 34.0 | Yes | 67.0 | Yes |
| 2022-07-04 | 47.0 | Yes | 66.0 | No | 55.0 | Yes |

The data is highly seasonal, but also has many missing values for both the target store and the similar stores used. There are about 600 days of sales for the stores.

Also, it is worth noting that A/B testing with a Synthetic Control fails here, because the Promotions are very highly synchronous across stores. That is, there is a very high probability that if my target store has an ongoing Promotion, so will the stores Similar to it. (but not necessarily)

I'd like the resulting table to look something like:

| Date | Target Store Sales | Target Store Sales Without Promotion | Target Store Promotion | Sales_Store1 | Promotion_Store1 | Sales_Store2 | Promotion_Store1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-30 | 55.0 | 45.0 | Yes | 34.0 | Yes | 67.0 | Yes |
| 2022-07-04 | 47.0 | 32.0 | Yes | 66.0 | No | 55.0 | Yes |

Do you know which model or technique could help me predict this baseline? I was looking into the new [Tide](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/examples/18-TiDE-examples.html#) but before delving into it and trying to use it, I thought I'd ask to see if anyone has faced a similar challenge. Thanks in advance!

I initially tried typical A/B testing while eliminating covariates, but the remaining data samples were too few. As I mentioned, most Promotions happen at the same times across stores.

I have tried training an XGBoost Regressor using the features above (and features like Month and Weekday) hoping to capture the seasonality, but have gotten mediocre results with a MAPE of around 0.15.